# React accessing custom state field from location.state

Tags: reactjs, location, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement a redirect after logging in. But there will be custom routes passed when getting to the login page which varies on which button is pressed etc.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
 const location = useLocation();
 const [claimUrl, setClaimUrl] = useState({});
 useEffect(() => {
        location.state && setClaimUrl(location.state.claimUrl);
    }, [location]);
...
};
```

I'm getting an error:
`Property 'claimUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.`

So is there a way I can define it on the location?

Any help/advice would be great.

Comment: Is the Login component nested within the react router context provider?

Comment: Hi @KennyJohnJacob I've added the index, app, and route code for context. I'm not 100% sure if it meets the router context?

Comment: Okay, now there is more clarity, so the Login component is nested in the SignIn component?

Comment: Yea it’s a child of SignIn component @KennyJohnJacob. Does that make a difference to the router?

Comment: No, it should be fine. What is the claimUrl that is being passed?

Comment: It looks like this @KennyJohnJacob `history.push('/sign-in', { claimUrl: '/claim' })`. When I console.log the location.state, I can see it as `{ claimUrl: '/claim' }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219909/discussion-between-kenny-john-jacob-and-designtocode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure this out by adding the field to `useLocation()`.

```
const location = useLocation<{
        claimUrl: unknown;
    }>();
```