# React : How to retain state of the previous page while navigating from one screen to other

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and react router. Previously I was working on react-native and react navigation. In react navigation, if I navigate from screen 1 to screen 2 and then come back to screen 1, the state of screen 1 was retained as it was. But how do I get the same result using react and react-router

My specific requiement is if an accrodian is opened in screen 1 and I navigate to screen 2 and then comeback to screen 1, I want the accordian to be still open. i.e, state of the page should be retained. How to achive this using react and react-router-dom

Comment: You can use `useLocation` from react-router-dom and pass through a variable with state or data. [A question I asked a while ago with the how I approached it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437453/react-accessing-custom-state-field-from-location-state/63438203#63438203)

Comment: @designtocode But I have to pass state/data from screen 1 to screen 2 and again pass back the data back to screen 1. Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: That is the easier solution. But you can use [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and store a global accordion state and update the state using dispatch and actions in your components. Then this state will be available throughout your app. This is a better option but requires extra work with store, actions etc.